# Unrecognized selector sent to instance while calling the dylib method

Tags: macos, cocoa, dylib

I have the following code to load a dylib:

```
void* lib_handle = dlopen("./newCocoaLib.dylib", RTLD_LOCAL);
if (!lib_handle) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


// Get the Person class from newCocoaLib.dylib.
Class Person_class = NSClassFromString(@"newCocoaLib");
if (!Person_class) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

id personObj = [Person_class new];
//calling the method of newCocoaLib of newCocoaLib.dylib
[personObj displayNameFromNewCocoaLib];//unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What might be the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: 2012-04-26 09:41:11.237 sample_loadCocoaDll[293:503] -[newCocoaLib displayNameFromNewCocoaLib]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89e1e13e30
2012-04-26 09:41:11.238 sample_loadCocoaDll[293:503] -[newCocoaLib displayNameFromNewCocoaLib]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89e1e13e30

Comment: Finally got it called,I cleaned and built the dylib and installed to /usr/lib directory.Thats it.